# How to change a whole column value in ListView in WPF (C# or VB)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, data-binding, listviewitem

Recently I’ve been working on a project where I need to change the column value of a listview
like when the user clicks on the start button, it changes the whole column text to ‘Searching,’ and after that, each cell of the column changes its text to completed, retry, captcha, etc.
how can I achieve this again I’m using listView
here is what my list looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5wyY.png)

when I click the button the waiting should be changed to searching and after the delay of each cell should change to completed, reserved, retry, etc. There is no logic behind it just to change the random text
here is what I’m looking for
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iu13.gif)

You can see there is a certain amount of delay between every cell change

Code for delay don't have much knowledge about tasks and threads

```
Private Async Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    Await BadLoopAsync(myType)
End Sub
Public Async Function Searching(item As Custom_Type) As Task

    item.Status1 = "Searching"
    item.BackColor1 = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
End Function
Public Async Function BadLoopAsync(ByVal thingsToLoop As IEnumerable(Of Custom_Type)) As Task
    For Each thing In thingsToLoop
        Await Searching(thing)
    Next
End Function
```

**Window Code**

```
 ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.DataContext = Me

    Dim type1 = New Custom_Type("site.org", "Snow Globe - Coke Bottel", "Luminati", "abc@gmail.com", "$1.22", "Waiting", New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(44, 184, 185)))

    myType = New ObservableCollection(Of Custom_Type)()
    For i = 0 To 10
        myType.Add(type1)
    Next
    myType.Add(type1)
    listView.ItemsSource = myType
 Private Async Function ChangeItemsStateAsync(ByVal state As String, ByVal color As Color, ByVal isDelayed As Boolean) As Task
    Dim randomGenerator = New Random()
    Dim coloredItems As List(Of Custom_Type) = Me.myType.ToList()

    While coloredItems.Any()
        Dim randomIndex As Integer = randomGenerator.[Next](0, coloredItems.Count - 1)
        Dim item As Custom_Type = coloredItems(randomIndex)
        coloredItems.RemoveAt(randomIndex)
        item.Status1 = state
        item.BackColor1 = New SolidColorBrush(color)

        If isDelayed Then
            Dim delayInMilliseconds As Integer = randomGenerator.[Next](125, 3000)
            Await Task.Delay(delayInMilliseconds)
        End If
    End While
End Function
```

**Custom_Type.class**

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class Custom_Type
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private Property site As String
Private Property item As String
Private Property proxy As String
Private Property profile As String
Private Property dollars As String
Private Property status As String

```
Public Property backColor As SolidColorBrush

Sub New(site As String, item As String, proxy As String, profile As String, dollars As String, status As String, backColor As SolidColorBrush)
    Me.site = site
    Me.item = item
    Me.proxy = proxy
    Me.profile = profile
    Me.dollars = dollars
    Me.status = status
    Me.backColor = backColor
End Sub
Sub New(status As String, backColor As SolidColorBrush)
    Me.status = status
    Me.backColor = backColor
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
Sub New()

End Sub
Public Property Status1 As String
    Get
        Return Me.status
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.status = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Status1")
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Item1 As String
    Get
        Return Me.item
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.item = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Item1")
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Proxy1 As String
    Get
        Return Me.proxy
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.proxy = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Proxy1")
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Profile1 As String
    Get
        Return Me.profile
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.profile = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Profile1")
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Dollars1 As String
    Get
        Return Me.dollars
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.dollars = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Dollars1")
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Site1 As String
    Get
        Return Me.site
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.site = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Site1")
    End Set
End Property
Public Property BackColor1 As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return Me.backColor
    End Get
    Set(value As SolidColorBrush)
        Me.backColor = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BackColor1")
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class
**ListView Code**

```
        <ListView Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="listView" Margin="25,10,0,60" Background="Transparent"
              BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding myType}" AlternationCount="2" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Site1}" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Site" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Item" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Proxy1}" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Proxy" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Profile1}" Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Profile" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dollars1}" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Dollars" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Status" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="txtBorder" CornerRadius="5" Background="{Binding BackColor1}" Width="80" Height="27"
                                    Padding="0,5,0,5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status1, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                           Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonIcon}"
                                    hc:IconElement.Geometry="{StaticResource down}" Foreground="White" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Action" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>

                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Please let me know where I'm doing a mistake

Comment: You should change the value of the status property of each data model. This should be obvious. So I guess I didn't understood your problem properly.

Comment: I want to change the status value after clicking a button. Is there any code snippet to get the idea from?

Comment: Just access the source collection. The items, that define the status property, must implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that the binding can update and read the changed value.

Comment: ohhh I haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged thanks for the suggestion I'll try and will let you know the results

Comment: @BionicCode, after implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, I'm able to change values, but things are changing at once. I need to have an effect like the image given in the above question; after changing one field, it should wait and change another, and this should also be affected in listview tried different methods like await or thread.sleep but unable to get the  desire results

Comment: Is there any reason for the delay or is it just artificial because you like it as a visual effect? Can you please post the code where you set the properties so that I can review it and suggest a solution? Also please show a version where you tried to wait. Maybe we can fix it.

Comment: @BionicCode yes it's just artificial added the code for delay

Comment: So, there is no real operation behind the states that probably execute on a background thread? This is just fake?

Comment: @BionicCode yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through each element in code behind and set the waiting value. Then set the new value for each cell after the operation for that cell finished. Like BionicCode I do not get the problem exactly

Comment: is there any code snipped to get an idea basically, I just want to change the status column values first all to searching and then, like in the image

Answer (score 0):

First, let your data model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([Microsoft Docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples)).
Then iterate over your source collection. You can use Task.Delay to force the loop to slow down (in times where users seek to have the fastest machine to make them wait less):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ColoredItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ColoredItem}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
          <TextBlock.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
          </TextBlock.Background>
        </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```vb
Public Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Public ReadOnly Property ColoredItems As ObservableCollection(Of ColoredItem)

    ' The cancellation source, which must be disposed after use.
    ' You can only use it once.
    Private Property CancellationTokenSource As CancellationTokenSource

    Public Sub New(ByVal dataContext As TestViewModel)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = Me
        Me.ColoredItems = New ObservableCollection(Of ColoredItem) From {
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green),
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green),
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green),
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green),
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green),
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green),
            New ColoredItem("Waiting", Colors.Green)
        }
    End Sub   

    ' Add CancellationToke parameter for cancellation support
    Private Async Function ChangeItemsStateAsync(
        ByVal state As String, 
        ByVal color As Color, 
        ByVal isDelayed As Boolean, 
        ByVal cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

        Dim randomGenerator = New Random()
        Dim coloredItems As List(Of ColoredItem) = Me.ColoredItems.ToList()

        While coloredItems.Any()
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

            Dim randomIndex As Integer = randomGenerator.[Next](0, coloredItems.Count - 1)
            Dim item As ColoredItem = coloredItems(randomIndex)
            coloredItems.RemoveAt(randomIndex)
            item.Text = state
            item.Color = color

            If isDelayed Then
                Dim delayInMilliseconds As Integer = randomGenerator.[Next](125, 3000)
                Await Task.Delay(delayInMilliseconds, cancellationToken)
            End If
        End While
    End Function

    ' The Button.Click handler for the cancel button
    Private Sub OnCancelButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Using Me.CancellationTokenSource AS CancellationTokenSource New CancellationTokenSource()

            Try
                Await ChangeItemsStateAsync("Searching", Colors.Orange, False, Me.CancellationTokenSource.Token)
                Await ChangeItemsStateAsync("Delayed", Colors.Red, True, Me.CancellationTokenSource.Token)
            Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

**ColoredItem.cs**

```vb
Public Class ColoredItem
    Inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String, ByVal color As Color)
        Me.Color = color
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub

    Private color As Color

    Public Property Color As Color
        Get
            Return Me.color
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            Me.color = value
            OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private text As String

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return Me.text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.text = value
            OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

---

After reviewing your code i found the following error that causes the ill behavior:
The posted code of your `MainWindow` class looks incomplete. However, the partial constructor you have showed is the reason for your ill behaving code. You only create a single instance of `Custom_Type`, named `type1`. The collection contains the same instance multiple times (10 times). But it must be individual instances, of course. Make sure to move the assignment of `type1` inside the loop.
Furthermore, you have added the line `myType.Add(type1)` twice. Remove the one outside of the loop.

```vb
myType = New ObservableCollection(Of Custom_Type)()

For i = 0 To 10
  Dim type1 = New Custom_Type("site.org", "Snow Globe - Coke Bottel", "Luminati", "abc@gmail.com", "$1.22", "Waiting", New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(44, 184, 185)))
  myType.Add(type1)
Next

listView.ItemsSource = myType
```

Comment: thanks for the effort you made this is what i was looking for

Comment: after adding your function to my project my data is still changing at once  I'll add the code above

Comment: This is not possible. Have you copy and pasted the complete examnple into a new project? Please don't mix it with your code. Create a new solution to test it. I was wondering before, because the code you have posted should work in the first place. I basically added random collection access and random delay and a slightly different method design. Please try the example in a new project. I assume you have not posted a code version that reproduces your issue. If my example works, please create a minimal version of your code that produces the issue you are experiencing, so that I can review it.

Comment: yes your example works perfect and I did create a new project to test it and it works like a charm but in your case, you were using Listbox and I'm using listview is there should be a problem with it furthermore I didn't use '<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ColoredItem}">' in my listview rest is the same as yours

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are using a ListView. You can replace the ListBox in this example and create a single column. It will still work.

Comment: I have posted code that is involved in this function can you review it?

Comment: Yes, but you must be absolutely sure that this is a version that reproduces the issue...

Comment: It must compile. i won't run it but you must be sure that it contains no errors like copy&paste errors etc.

Comment: I have did twice but let me review it for you once again

Comment: Thank you. The posted code of your MainWindow class looks incomplete. However, the partial constructor you have showed is the reason for your ill behaving code. You only create a single instance of `Custom_Type`, named `type1`. The collection contains the same instance multiple times (10 times). But it must be individual instances. Make sure to move the assignment of `type1` inside the loop. I have updated my answer to highlight the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of reviewing the code before I was using 'Public Property myType As ObservableCollection(Of Custom_Type)' 'Dim type1 = New Custom_Type(data)' and then was adding type1 in myType(type1) through loop and now I have changed it to your code 'myType = New ObservableCollection(Of Custom_Type) From {data}' and now it's working perfect any idea why adding looping data wasn't working

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. It means a lot. I was stuck here for the past few days. I wish I could upvote this answer 100 times, but unfortunately, I can't even do it once as I'm at three reputations. Thank again. God bless you

Comment: Good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: I also forget to tell you that if you use the `CallerMemberName` attribute with you `NotifyPropertyChanged` method (like you did), then you don't need to pass in the property name as a parameter. The attribute tells the compiler to use the name of the member that called the method. The member in this case is the property that calls `NotifyPropertyChanged()`. So you can safely remove all the property name strings. Simply call `NotifyPropertyChanged();` in the property setter.

Comment: @BionicCide  Ahhh, That's why it was missing from your code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @BioniCode I also have a stop button to stop the task how can I stop the when I click on stop button

Comment: I have updated the example. The key to cancel an asynchronous operation is to use the `CancellationTokenSource`. Note how each method that supports cancellation accepts a common `CancellationToken` parameter. When the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method is called the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method will throw to cancel the operation. The caller of the cancelled async method must catch the `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: Every async method of the Task library accepts a `CancellationToken` for cancellation. Note how the above example passes a token to the `Task.Delay` to make it cancelable.See [Cancel an Async Task or a List of Tasks (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-an-async-task-or-a-list-of-tasks)

Comment: sorry to bother you again can I change the order of text like first all items should be searching then after 5 to 6 sec each item must follow this order
reserving>captcha>purchased and there shouldn't be a captcha more than 2 to 3 times then reserving>purchased. Is this possible to achieve?